# What does the last parameter in JsonFX Deserializer mean?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I saw a JsonFX Deserialize statement using a parameter that I can't find the meaning of:

```
JsonFx.Json.JsonReader.Deserialize<TOTmapData>(map.text)
```

I know that TOTmapData is a Class but what is (map.text)? Is that a cast?

I googled it and found many different examples of that last parameter like
(response), (testJson), (sMy), etc. But I can't find any explanation of what it is exactly.

Answer (score 2):

`Deserialize()` is a function. `map.text` is just a parameter pass to it. You should have somewhere a object named `map` and this object has an property `text`. Your function `Deserialize()` will do something to this text. I guess it is a string, probably a raw of json and you are going to deserialize it into a TOTmapData object.

`response), (testJson), (sMy)` are just name of others variables.

I can do

```
string s = " *some json for TOTmapData* ".
var totmapdata = JsonFx.Json.JsonReader.Deserialize<TOTmapData>(s);
// here my "s" is a variable like your map.text;
```

Comment: text is a property or field.not an attribute

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I had a brain fart this morning.

Comment: No problem. If the problem is solved, can you mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you [cross-posted this on the Unity forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/232740-What-does-the-last-parameter-in-JsonFX-Deserializer-mean) as well I assume you are using JsonFx 1.x or a fork of it. Also the method signature is different in [JsonFx 2](https://github.com/jsonfx/jsonfx).

The correct answer is it depends on which method overload you are using, but given that the property name is `map.text` then it is most likely the overload that takes a `string`. In that case the `string` is the JSON text to be parsed and the `T` result is the deserialized object graph:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string value);
```

I'm not familiar with Unity enough to know what that environment is like, but C# is a statically typed language so any decent IDE should be able to show you the API contract that you are interfacing with pretty easily. At the very least, since JsonFx is open source, you can always look at what is going on under the hood as well:

https://code.google.com/p/jsonfx/source/browse/trunk/JsonFx/JsonFx.Json/JsonReader.cs#938